# Start dialer.exe from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, shell, batch-file

I am actually around the internet development for quite a while now - but I never had to do the following and have no idea how to solve it:

Our computers have connected Telephones which are used with the Dialer.exe.

As I am working on an internal Clientdatabase in our network I would like to support the feature of clicking a "link" == telephonnumber in the browser in our database -> that click should execute the following task : open dialer.exe on users C:// , paste in telephonenumber in numberfield.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since I have no idea how to approach this particular issue I have tried several things i've found on the net. Basically its not more than altering the hrefs of all phonenumbers to file://batchfile.batch which should fire a batch file on the server with content like this : start /d "C:\Windows\System32\" dialer.exe 004321341233

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible by adapting a Costum-URI-Sheme to your needs. See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Problematic is that this solution is yet Windows only and that you need to set registry-entries on every machine. Probably those values are applicable with an appropriate infrastructure but if there's not domain existent this could be a horrendous amount of work...

Edit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telephone]
@="URL:Telephone Dialer"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telephone\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dialer.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telephone\shell]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telephone\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\telephone\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\dialer.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: I am not pleased by the amount of work behind that "simple" task .. Have you ever done this ?

Comment: No I haven't had to use it by now. It's fairly simple, the article is explaining it very well and if you want me to, I will try to figure out a solution for you. The problem that you need to access all machines to make it work globally, is rather no fault of the Uri-Scheme. You can export those keys if you created them once and maybe distribute them with an USB-Stick or something. To apply it everywhere you will definitly need to modify each system so you won't come around of that...

Comment: I have access to all computers individually - that shouldn't be a problem ->  also there would be only 8~ machines involved in the whole database structure. I don't want you to do the work for me obviously but I am thankfull for any "Hey man, create a file in your root of the server with that example content in the batch file : "xxx" - you could access the batch file through browser like that : "XY", etc" I don't know where to start when I look at the article - I think thats my main problem :)

Comment: I dont think thats possible, running batch scripts directly from the browser would conceal big security issues, imagine everybody can access your Windows system just by passing arguments to scripts and executables and let them run without the user to know... Another possible solution would be VBScript I guess. You would be forced to use the Internet-Explorer and lower your security settings but maybe you get the chance to run the dialer script from there on.

Comment: Sounds bad indeed. Using IE doesn't scare me - I can always advise my fellow collegues to use IE when operating with the clientdatabase. So what should I do ? 
P.S. I didn't know VisualBasic scripts can be called and altered by browser events

Comment: I added a solution to my initial post above. The common URI to invoke telephone calls is "tel:" but to differentiate between Skype and other VoIP-Services I changed it to telephone in this example. You can paste it 1:1 to a .key file and entry it in your Registry. Afterwards you will be able to call the dialer.exe by writing "telephone:1234567" in the browser, this also works for links etc. The registry-key will be created like described on the Technet-site below the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT-tree, so take a look into it, if you are interested for the next time :)